# ACRA not catching exceptions (with parse.com custom ReportSender)

Tags: java, android, acra

I have added the latest ACRA:

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.8.5'
```

Configured my App class according to docs:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        reportSenderFactoryClasses = {com.github.dht.screenger.crash.ParseSenderfactory.class}
)

...

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);

}
```

Defined the Sender factory:

```
public class ParseSenderfactory implements ReportSenderFactory {

// NB requires a no arg constructor.

public ReportSender create(Context context, ACRAConfiguration config){
    return new ParseSender();
    }
}
```

The sender:

```
public class ParseSender implements ReportSender {

    @Override
    public void send(Context context, CrashReportData report) throws ReportSenderException {

        // Get the ParseObject to be send to Parse
        CrashReportParseObject crashReport = getParseObject(report);

        // Associate the current logged user with the crash report
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        crashReport.setUser(currentUser);

        // Send crash report to Parse
        crashReport.saveInBackground();
    }

    /**
     * Get a custom ParseObject for data collected by ACRA.
     * @param report
     * Report data collected by ACRA.
     * @return
     * A custom ParseObject containing relevant data.
     */
    private CrashReportParseObject getParseObject(Map<ReportField, String> report) {
        ReportField[] fields = ACRA.getConfig().customReportContent();
        if (fields.length == 0) {
            fields = ACRAConstants.DEFAULT_REPORT_FIELDS;
        }
        CrashReportParseObject finalReport = new CrashReportParseObject();
        for (ReportField field : fields) {
            finalReport.put(field.toString(), report.get(field));
        }
        return finalReport;
    }

}
```

And the ParseObject:

```
@ParseClassName("CrashReport")
public class CrashReportParseObject extends ParseObject {

    public String getAndroidVersion(){
        return this.getString("ANDROID_VERSION");
    }

    public String getAppVersionName(){
        return this.getString("APP_VERSION_NAME");
    }

    public String getPhoneModel(){
        return this.getString("PHONE_MODEL");
    }

    public String getProduct(){
        return this.getString("PRODUCT");
    }

    public void setUser(ParseUser user){
        this.put("user", user);
    }
}
```

And yet ACRA does not catch an exception I send from the activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");

}
```

Did I forget something?

**UPDATE**

Made some progress. Saw the CrashReportParseObject was not being created as Parse wanted the syntax to be ParseObject.create("CrashReport");

Changed the ParseSender to :

```
public class ParseSender implements ReportSender {

    @Override
    public void send(Context context, CrashReportData report) throws ReportSenderException {

        Log.d("ACRA", "Sending log");
        // Get the ParseObject to be send to Parse
        ParseObject crashReport = getParseObject(report);

        // Associate the current logged user with the crash report
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        crashReport.put("user", currentUser);

        Log.d("ACRA", crashReport.toString());
        // Send crash report to Parse
        crashReport.saveInBackground();
    }

    /**
     * Get a custom ParseObject for data collected by ACRA.
     *
     * @param report Report data collected by ACRA.
     * @return A custom ParseObject containing relevant data.
     */
    private ParseObject getParseObject(Map<ReportField, String> report) {
        ReportField[] fields = ACRA.getConfig().customReportContent();
        if (fields.length == 0) {
            fields = ACRAConstants.DEFAULT_REPORT_FIELDS;
        }
        ParseObject finalReport = new ParseObject("CrashReport");
        for (ReportField field : fields) {
            if (field.toString() != null && report.get(field) != null) {
                finalReport.put(field.toString(), report.get(field));
            }

        }
        return finalReport;
    }

}
```

and removed CrashReportParseObject all together. Now I am getting "ACRA caught a RuntimeException for com.github.dht.screenger" but still no object is being created on parse.com. Is it a timing thing? does the app crash before it gets the time save the object?

Comment: Does acra not send the report or do you not receive it?

Comment: Is the `send()` method on your `ParseSender` being called? What does the logcat say?

Comment: I put a breakpoint at the first line of the "send" method. It never reaches it.

Comment: If this is still a problem I recommend to turn on ACRA logging and check the outputs.